# Use urllib2 to Loop Through Page Content

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm relatively new to python so things like this are not coming easy to me.

I just want to loop through a web pages content and then print each occurrence to the console window for now but I obviously have my loop wrong.

```
import sys
import re
import urllib2
import urlparse

crawling = tocrawl.pop()
response = urllib2.urlopen(crawling)

msg = response.read()
endDiv = msg.find('</div>')
while endDiv != -1:
    endDiv = msg.find('</div>')
    startPos = msg.find('class="facultyname">', endDiv)
    if startPos != -1:
        nextPos = msg.find('.php">', startPos)
        endPos = msg.find('</a>', nextPos)
    if endPos != -1:
        name = msg[nextPos+6:endPos]
        print name, "   ",

    startPos = msg.find('function escramble()')
    if startPos != -1:
        nextPos = msg.find('b=', startPos)
        endPos = msg.find('c', nextPos)
    if endPos != -1:
        email = msg[nextPos+3:endPos-1]
        email = email[:-13] + '@email.com'
        print email

    endDiv = msg.find('</div>', endPos)
```

I'm already grabbing the first occurrence, I just want to loop until the end of the page and collect the rest.

Sample HTML:

```
<div id="main-text">

   <p class="title">Research Scientists</p>


   <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>
   <img src="photos/icons/bastolaicon.jpg" class="faculty" width="53" height="71" alt="Bastola Photo" />

   <div class="facultyname">
     <strong><a href="people/bastola.php">person1</a>
     <br /><em>Post-Doctoral Scientist</em></strong>
     <br />
   </div>

   <div class="facultybody">
     Rm. 218A
     <br /><em><script type="text/javascript">

       <!--
       function escramble(){
       var a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
       a='<a href=\"mai'
       b='person1'
       c='\">'
       a+='lto:'
       b+='@'
       e='</a>'
       f=''
       b+='email.com'
       g='<img src=\"'
       h=''
       i='\" alt="Email us." border="0">'

       if (f) d=f
       else if (h) d=g+h+i
       else d=b

       document.write(a+b+c+d+e)
       }
       escramble()
       //-->

       </script></em>

   </div>

   <div class="space">&nbsp;</div>

   <img src="photos/icons/person2icon.jpg" class="faculty" width="53" height="71" alt="person2 Photo" />

   <div class="facultyname">
     <strong><a href="people/person2.shtml">person2</a>
     <br /><em>Assistant Research Scientist</em></strong>
     <br />
   </div>

   <div class="facultybody">
     Rm. 227
     <br />(850) 645-1253
     <br /><em><script type="text/javascript">

       <!--
       function escramble(){
       var a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i
       a='<a href=\"mai'
       b='person2'
       c='\">'
       a+='lto:'
       b+='@'
       e='</a>'
       f=''
       b+='email.com'
       g='<img src=\"'
       h=''
       i='\" alt="Email us." border="0">'

       if (f) d=f
       else if (h) d=g+h+i
       else d=b

       document.write(a+b+c+d+e)
       }
       escramble()
       //-->

       </script></em>

   </div>

   <div class="spacer">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: If you want to grab data and elements of the document, your best shot would be [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Do you have a small set of sample HTML? I have a feeling this would be much better suited to `beautifulsoup` or `lxml.html` ... (although it does look like you're trying to find something within a JS fuction)

Comment: I don't want to make it too complicated. I just want to scrub the page for the data found between these positions. I'm already grabbing the first occurrence, I just want to loop until the end of the page and collect the rest.

Comment: @frankV the point we're trying to make is that you may be making it complicated with this approach :)

Comment: I am grabbing something from a js function. This script works; it only grabs the first instance though.

Comment: you could use http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer to find all matches

Comment: Without sample data, I don't think anyone can help you with this...

Comment: @JonClements added sample data

Comment: I have it looping now, but it's only looping over the first occurrence and therefor printing it out repeatedly since it's stuck in an infinite loop somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty approach that works for your sample data:

```
>>> res = re.findall(r"b\+?='(.*?)'", html)
>>> res
['person1', '@', 'email.com', 'person2', '@', 'email.com']
>>> emails [''.join(group) for group in zip(*[iter(res)]*3)]
['person1@email.com', 'person2@email.com']
```

And since this is already horrible then let's really kludge it:

```
>>> names = [name.split('>', 1)[1] for name in re.findall(r'href="people(.*?)</a>', html)]
>>> names
['person1', 'person2']
>>> zip(names, emails)
[('person1', 'person1@email.com'), ('person2', 'person2@email.com')]
```

**Note - this just works on your sample data - HTML is fickle - so don't expect this to be robust - easily managable etc... etc...**

Comment: I may not know how to implement that correctly because it errors with `html is not defined`

Comment: @frankV added another kludge to it

Comment: `html` is in this case your sample data - it's what you've called `msg`

Comment: I installed BeauifulSoup and after some problems parsing html and which parser worked best on my machine I finally got it working. Thanks for the tip, if you rewrite your answer to include this I'll accept it.

Comment: @frankV I'll be happy to accept an edit to my answer with your discovery - don't forget this is a community after all